# How to make a UIScrollView with buttons accessible?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, accessibility, voiceover

I have a horizontal `UIScrollView` with buttons. A custom toolbar at the bottom. The user can scroll it left / right.

Problem is with VoiceOver when I set the `UIScrollView` as `self.isAccessibilityElement = YES`, VoiceOver ignores the buttons on the `UIScrollView`.

When I don't do it, VoiceOver finds the buttons. But user can't scroll up/down.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want `isAccessibilityElement` set to `YES` on the container (your `UIScrollView`), you only want it set on the individual buttons.

Scrolling doesn't work the same with VoiceOver, see the "[Learn VoiceOver gestures](http://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1565/en_US/iphone_user_guide.pdf)" section in the manual.